# Can you switch CocoaLumberJack logging from asynchronous to synchronous at run time? Or force a flush of pending writes?

Tags: ios, cocoalumberjack

I'm using CocoaLumberJack to write to a logging file and I want to be able to attach the file/and or its contents to upload for analysis during execution if the app detects an unexpected situation while its running.

In which case I want to log to be up to date and contain all logging that might have been written just microseconds before.

i.e. given this code:

```
  DDLogWarn(@"%@", @"Want this line to appear in the file");
  if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:logthLocation.path]) {
      NSError* error = nil;
      NSStringEncoding encoding = 0;
      NSString *contents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:logURL
                                                       usedEncoding:&encoding
                                                              error:&error];
```

Then the contents string won't contain the line just previously written.

The async/sync writing nature can be set at compile time via  setting `#define LOG_ASYNC_ENABLED` to YES or NO

However for efficiency I want logging to be asynchronous by default, but to be able to flush any pending writes before opening the file.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

[DDLog flushLog] seems to do the job